# Xdebug Breakpoints ignored in modules included by php module autoloader

Tags: php, xdebug, phpstorm

stumbled over the following question, while debugging my php scripts with xdebug. if i manually include/require a module setting breakpoints in the modules code works, no problem. breakpoints inside a module included by my project's autoloader are ignored. anybody had the same problem? is there a workaround? thanks!

my setup:

- osx 10.7.2
- mamp 2.0.3
- php 5.3.6
- xdebug 2.1.0
- phpstorm 3.0 eap (Listen PHP Debug Connections debug mode)

Answer (score 1):

Do you use symlinks in your modules? In could be related to the path am

Comment: i don't use symlinks in my modules, but it might be related to the include paths, or to php's spl_autoload function. i've deactivated the "clean" autoloader function and enabled the "dirty" function (include module with absolute path). and this way it works. so it might have something to do with the global include paths .. i continue debugging

Comment: it works when i use xdebug_break() to set a breakpoint, might have to do with the way spl_autoload works .. i keep on researching/debugging (TIPP with xdebug_break i got from [link](http://www.noodlecake.com/?p=105) )

Comment: I need an xdebug problem session log (xdebug.org/docs/remote#remote_log) to be able to help you. Please create a thread about the problem on PhpStorm discussions forum - devnet.jetbrains.com/community/wi?view=discussions. Thanks!

Comment: thanx, i'm very busy this week, but i'll definitely will do that